# Siteminder and Office 365 integration

Tags: office365, saml, siteminder

Anybody impelemented Siteminder and Office 365 integration? When i read Siteminder documentation about integrating office 365 with Siteminder, it metnioned to use SAML 1.1. Is this the only you can implement it or can we use SAML 2.0 too? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

WF-Federation and WS-Trust is required. CA has an entire 40page Runbook on how to set it up using v12.52

https://search.ca.com/assets/SiteAssets/TEC618461_External/CASM-MSOffice365FederationRunbook-ver1.0.pdf

Comment: Ian, In that document they mentioned to use SAML 1.1.. so was wondering why can't we use SAML 2.0

Comment: Because MS (currently) doesn't support that.